# Copying files to external drive: Target directory path invalid

Tags: python, linux, directory, copy

I'm writing a script that copies all files in my home directory to a specific partition on an external drive. However, I'm having trouble inputting the output path for the files to be copied to. Here's my script:

```
import sys
import getopt
import os
import shutil

def copy_files(source, target):
    """Copies all files from the source directory to the target directory."""
    shutil.copy(source, target)

def main(argv):
    """Main function."""
    source_dir = ''
    target_dir = ''

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            source_dir = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            target_dir = arg
    print('Source directory is "', source_dir)
    print('Backup directory is "', target_dir)

    # Check if source_dir and target_dir are valid directories
    if os.path.isdir(source_dir):
        print('Source directory is valid.')
    else:
        print('Error: Source directory is NOT valid.')
        exit()

    if os.path.isdir(target_dir):
        print('Target directory is valid.')
    else:
        print('Error: Target directory is NOT valid.')
        exit()

    if os.path.isdir(source_dir) and os.path.isdir(target_dir):
        copy_files(source_dir, target_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

For the command input, I have tested both of these lines in command terminal:

```
backup_critical_files.py -i ~ -o /run/media/lemons/[NAME OF DRIVE]/'
backup_critical_files.py -i ~ -o /dev/sda1
```

Is there a specific path that I am missing here? Do I need to create a folder and specify that folder on the external drive?

Comment: Which version of linux are you running?  `/run/media/lemons/` looks like an odd mountpoint to me, and writing to the raw-device `/dev/sda1`  is **definitely** a bad idea (should you succeed).

Comment: P.S.: Why reinvent the wheel when Linux comes with `rsync`?

Comment: 1. I'm running an arch linux distro called EndeavourOS. 2. lemons is an example username. 3. I know that rsync exists, yet I'm practicing writing a script that backs up critical files. 4. I'm not cloning my entire drive, rather copying a few dozen or so gigs of files.